# Running an app/service in deep sleep mode?

Tags: android

Im planning to write an app which will do a task every 5 mins, in background. What will happen if the phone goes to sleep?

I heard that in deep sleep, cpu turns off, so apps stop executing, and someone also said that cpu doesn't turn off, but runs in frequency below 100mhz? Which one is true?

also, if apps don't run in deep sleep, how do we recive calls and sms in real time?

Im completely new to Android and have just installed the sdk.

Comment: Most phones have two processor cores - the app cpu sleeps, while the radio cpu runs in a low power mode keeping tabs on the mobile network, hardware button pushes, etc.  Note this is different than what are advertised as "dual core" phones which would probably have 3 - a radio CPU plus two app cpu's.  Preset wakeup timers are small bits of circuitry which consume little power to keep running.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion. im now using Alarm manager to wake up my phone during sleep.

Comment: You can also use WakeLock i will solve the issue of sleeping but it will drain battery....

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know what deep sleep is, but you can achieve this by making a service and have a timer that would fire every 5 minutes (300000 milliseconds).